# Can't compare strings in Java Android

Tags: java, android, string

I have looked for other and similar questions to my title. However, none of those answers work.

```
public void clickedCheck(View view) {

    String input = emojiconTextView.getText().toString();
    String input2 = myRandomImage.getDrawable().toString();

    if (input.equals(input2)) {
        checkingText.setText("Well Done!");
    }
}
```

However, the text doesn't change to "Well Done!". It stays to the default value I put.

I'm comparing the EmojiconTextView object to an ImageView object. If the 2 images are equal, it should display "Well Done!". The EmojiconTextView is from a Gradle dependency and library I've added.

Comment: because this `myRandomImage.getDrawable()` isnt going to be what you have in your emojiconTextView. its a drawable to an image

Comment: Print both values `input` & `input2`, you'll understand why it is not equal

Comment: @tyczj - So is there no possible way to do this?

Comment: what you are trying to do makes no sense, how can you possibly compare a string to an image?

Comment: @FirozMemon - will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your comparing the text value from a TextView and making it a string, and the text representation of the drawable.

Calling toString on Drawable will return string representation of drawable instead of drawable name. So the strings will never be equal.

```
//this is the string value of whatever is in the textview
String input = emojiconTextView.getText().toString();
// this is the text representation of a drawable. not the name of the drawable
String input2 = myRandomImage.getDrawable().toString();
```

Set the tag for the image

```
<ImageView ...
    android:tag="some tag"
/>
```

Try using `myRandomImage.getTag().toString()`

Comment: However now, how would I make it display "Unlucky" if the images are NOT equal?

Comment: @MSP Just replace the closing bracket on the if-statement with `} else {        checkingText.setText("Unlucky"); }`

Comment: @Dewick47 - I thought the same, but I've tried that, and it still displays "Well Done!"

Comment: @MSP Then you should debug why `input` is now always equal to `input2`. If you are still stuck after that, post a new question.

Comment: @Dewick47 - Will try debug now and will wait for a response from the correct answer.

Comment: @MSP different question traditionally requires different post

Comment: @ralphie9224 - Will post another question shortly, thank you though for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you're trying to get a "drawable" and use it's toString method, you'll likely get something other than what you're expecting. Not sure, and haven't tried it.. but from experience, it would seem that using the toString method on a "getDrawable" is going to yield something weird. You'll know if you debug and check the value of input2. Just my .02 cents.

Comment: This very much sounds more like a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I know.. but you have to have 50 reputation points to make a comment, apparently.